# Prove that the integral of an absolutely continuous function exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I'm trying to prove the following:

Show that the integral of an absolutely continuous function, which asymptotically converges to zero (so the function value is zero when its argument is infinity), exists. In other words, I need to show that the integral tends to some constant $c<\infty$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit** It's exactly the opposite of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444311/a-uniformly-continuous-function-whose-integral-int-0-infty-fxdx-exists-con).

Comment: What's the defintion of an absolutely continuous function on an unbounded interval?

Comment: I assumed that the definition of absolute continuity on a closed interval can be extended to a (half) open inteval, as discussed [in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/absolute-continuity-on-an-open-interval-of-the-real-line). Actually, I'm not a 100% sure if this assumption is justifiable.

Comment: Maybe assume the (AC) function is of the form $\int _a ^x f(t)\mu(\mathrm{d}t)$? That is, it is a Lebesgue's integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not true, as $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x + 1}$ is absolutely continuous over $[0, +\infty[$, tends to zero but has no definite integral.

Comment: An excellent example, thanks. But are there conditions that the function should satisfy in order for the limit of the integral to exist?

Comment: well, given that any continuous function with limit 0 at infinity is absolutely continuous, the conditions are the same as for any continuous function with limit 0.

Comment: Any idea where I can find those specific conditions? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are no simple conditions unfortunately other than just "be integrable". Also consider accepting the answer if it fits your question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your effort.